# Where is the CSS spec that says the "!important" takes precedence over inline element styles?

Tags: html, css, specifications

In all modern browsers, CSS rules declared with the `!important` keyword take precedence over all other declarations, even including those made inside the element `style` attribute.

Where in the CSS spec does it say it should override element `style` attribute rules? I am trying to find it here but am not having any luck:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#importance

I really don't like that it overrides element styles, and am wondering if this behavior was even in the specs to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right at the top of the [section on the cascade sort](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-sort)

> The cascade sorts declarations according to the following criteria, in descending order of priority:

The very **first** entry is:

> Origin and Importance

which includes all the `!important` rules.

The **third** entry is:

> Element-Attached Styles

Answer (score 2):

[Section 6.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-sort), above the link you give. [Origin and Importance](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-origin)  comes before [Element-Attached Styles](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#style-attr)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is described with the sentence:

> An **important** declaration takes precedence over a **normal** declaration.

(emphasis mine)

Where an important declaration has `!important` at the end and:

> All other declarations are normal (non-important).

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#importance

---

If you don't like that important styles have this trait, then don't use them—find a way to override non-inline styles using the other precedence rules. Generally, I would recommend using important styles only when truly necessary (e.g. to override a style that is defined inline by a third party).